# watchOS 9 WidgetKit complications missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement

Tags: healthkit, watchos, widgetkit

I have an iOS/wOS app that launched last year. Now I want to add complications to it and use the new way of doing complications with WidgetKit. I have everything in place up to the point where I'm supposed to read the data from Health to display it, where it fails with `Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement`.

This is the new extension I've added

[image]

It's embedded in the WatchKit app NOT in the WatchKit Extension and I've added permission to read health data directly in the `info.plist` for the extension

[image]

[image]

I pull the data from the `TimelineProvider` protocol method

```
 func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let currentDate = Date()
        
        var entries: [WorkoutEntry] = []
        
        ComplicationHealthManager.loadPreviousWorkouts { workout in
            let workoutEntry = WorkoutEntry(date: currentDate, workout: workout)
            entries.append(workoutEntry)
            
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(currentDate))
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
```

with the help of a small manager class

```
class ComplicationHealthManager: ObservableObject {
    static func loadPreviousWorkouts(completion: @escaping (HKWorkout?) -> Void) {
        let healthStore: HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
        let workoutPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .traditionalStrengthTraining)
        let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                            [workoutPredicate])
        
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate,
                                              ascending: false)
        
        let query = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: .workoutType(),
            predicate: compound,
            limit: 0,
            sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in
                guard
                    let samples = samples as? [HKWorkout],
                    error == nil
                else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                
                let calendar = Calendar.current
                let todaysSamples = samples.filter{ calendar.isDateInToday($0.endDate) }.last
                
                completion(todaysSamples)
            }
        
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
}
```

The issue is in the closure for the health query where it returns with no workouts but an error stating

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.}
```

The problem here is I don't understand where and how to add an entitlement for the complication extension or the WatchKit app, as none of them have the option for health. I have a health entitlements set for the iPhone app and the WatchKit Extension.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem to be that I had the old implementation of watchkit apps, with both a Watch app and a Watch extension. That was the problem. I went and used the migration from Xcode 14 to merge the Watch App and Extension into a new watch app and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please file a Feedback at feedback.apple.com for this.

You can manually add the HealthKit entitlement to the Code Signing Entitlements file (create a new one if there isn't one already) associated with the target

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: I actually tried that but then I get a warning that it can’t be signed as the provisioning profile doesn’t contain HealthKit entitlements